# Calling a 3D cube drawing method more than once in JAVA?

Tags: java, 3d, paint

I've drawn a 3D cube on an applet, it appeared fine, then I translated it to another coordinates and painted in again. So now I have both cubes on the applet.
But the second cube appeared distorted, How can I fix it???
I tried using a Buffered Image, it appeared fine, but in my project I'm not supposed to use it. Because at the end it's supposed to be animated all with translations and rotations. so using a Buffered Image would be useless here.
Any ideas?

Comment: espeically with animations, a buffered image is very useful! Check [this page](http://www.realapplets.com/tutorial/DoubleBuffering.html) about double buffering

Comment: "Any ideas?"  1) Post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html).  2) Provide screenshots of the current vs. expected behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for every frame, you have to draw the background, so the previously drawed gets deleted, and then draw the cube again.

However, If you wanna do more complicated 3d things, jME is a good, easy to understand 3d engine.